# What's the historical origin of the left-to-right order of operations?

Tags: notation, math-history

I would assume this question has been answered before, but no combination of Googling and searching StackExchange yielded an actual response.

The Facebook problem 6/2(1+2) is boring to discuss in terms of PEMDAS/BODMAS/PEMA, but a friend of mine gave me a question I couldn't answer. There are plenty of articles on the origin of this convention. But they always mention in passing that aside from that you evaluate left-to-right.

Where does this come from? I'm assuming this convention was introduced in a country that reads left-to-right. Has there been a time when mathematicians in Arabia, Japan, China, etc. evaluated in a different order?

Comment: Similar question asked in the past, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1246798/order-of-operations-in-different-cultures

Comment: Most western languages write horizontally. In that case, it is preferable to write from left to right to allow freshly written characters in ink more time to dry. In ancient time, chinese text are written vertically from top to bottom and then right to left. Their arithmetic problem are also presented in this order. e.g. see picture on [九章算術](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nine_Chapters_on_the_Mathematical_Art) on wiki.

Due to strong influence of chinese to japenese culture. I believe same thing happens to ancient japanese. No idea about various cultures in middle east.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you, I saw that one, but it doesn't really contain answers. Also it doesn't specifically address the left-to-right order I'm interested in. There's one data point in the comments, but the one answer has no substance.

Comment: @achillehui That's very cool, I'm wondering for how long they kept this up, considering the Chinese numbers are already inherently base 10, making them much more useful for math than Roman numerals. Also I studied some Chinese in university (nothing to write home about), and it's fascinating that most of the characters are still recognizable, while I couldn't read whatever my forefathers wrote ~2000-3000 years ago (if they wrote at all).

Comment: There is remarkable exception from the "left-to-right" convention: This is the composition of functions. Given functions $f : X \to Y$ and $g : X \to Z$, their composition is written as $g \circ f : X  \to Z$ although we **first** apply $f$ and in the **second step** $g$. Obviuosly this is the price for writing $f(x)$. This enforces writing $g(f(x))$ which lead to use $g \circ f$ for the functuon assigning to $x \in X$ the value $g(f(x)) \in Z$.

Comment: In Western world, writing is (quite all ?) from left to right.